# I have integrate mesibo in my angular app. local stream is working properly. but remote stream is not connected

Tags: javascript, angular, mesibo

I am using Angular cli --ssl to run it on HTTPS.

```
this.api.setupVideoCall('localVideo','remoteVideo',true)
```

[image]

I was following mesibo javascript basic demo app as a reference. Above code is called without any error but still local video working properly, remotevideo is not working. Please help with this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a browser security issue. You get media access (camera and microphone), you must run using the HTTPS URL and you MUST also use a valid certificate with recognized authority, the self-signed certificate will not work.

This restriction is by the browsers and not by the mesibo. Refer Mozilla documentation here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have already tried using HTTPS URL, It's not working. any other solutions,

Comment: Not only HTTPS, but you also need a valid certificate, self-signed certificate will not work. If that's not an issue share URL here so we all can see